# MKAnnotationView tap on title

Tags: swift4, mkannotationview

I want to customize my annotation view to show something like the image below. My questions are:

1) How can I customize the annotation view?
2) How can I make the app do something when user tap on the title? or tapped anywhere in the annotation view? if making it specific to the title is not possible!

I have added

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)
```

but it does not get called!

[image]

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381512/6541007) can be some help.

Comment: @OOPer thank you! but how about the other lines in the annotation view? is there a way to do this?

Comment: As far as I know, no, no way. You need to put any of the subclass of `UIControl`. But I do not have enough experience to remove _as far as I know_. You may find someone who knows, if you can clarify what you really want to do.